# Crystal Reports 8.5 duplex printing

Tags: crystal-reports

I have Cristal Reports 8.5 I need to reset page number for every new group, and if group contains odd number of pages need to add blank page, if there is even number of pages nothing should be done just reset page numbers.
I found many issues about this but nothing works as it should.
There is Group Header 1 anf Group Footer 1, and report need to be printed on duplex printer.
Thanks

Comment: kindly share some research you have done so far. refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713330/crystal-reports-create-intentionally-blank-page-for-duplex-printing

Comment: I tried this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713330/crystal-reports-create-intentionally-blank-page-for-duplex-printing. But it prints 3 blank pages when odd page numbers and 2 when even. When I Suppress GF1a and GF1b it prints one blank when odd page numbers, and no blank on even( thats good ) but page number is not reset ( need to be reset). Thanks

Comment: Did you check the "Reset Page Number After"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to make this work on a simple report with just one group:

1. First I created a new Group Footer section, Group Footer 1b
2. Group Header 1: on the Common tab only "Keep Together" is checked. On the Paging tab, in the formula field for "New Page Before", enter not `OnFirstRecord`
3. Detail Section: only check "Keep Together" on the Common tab
4. Group Footer 1: nothing is checked on either Common or Paging tab
5. Group Footer 1a: "Keep together" on Common tab, on Paging tab put `Remainder(PageNumber,2) =1` in the formula field under "New Page After"
6. Group Footer 1b: Check "keep Together" on Common tab, put `Remainder(PageNumber,2) = 1` in the formula field under Suppress.

This worked for me and will add a blank page if the group ends on an odd page.

Comment: I'm glad. Please make sure to upvote or mark as answered if an answer has helped you or solved your problem.

Comment: I needed a "Page N of M" display, and checking "Reset Page Number After" on Group Footer 1 worked for me.